# tcpdf tamil unicode மரபு wrongly print as மரபீ

Tags: unicode, tcpdf, tamil

`tdpdf` Tamil Unicode printing issue:
Trying multiple Unicode fonts like `freesans`, `freeserif`, `latha`.
But the Tamil word மர**பு** wrongly print as மர**பீ**
(Marabu as Marabee).

```
$x=5;
$pdf->SetFont('latha', 'N', 10);
$pdf->SetFont('freesans', 'N', 10);
$pdf->SetFont('freeserif', 'N', 10);
$pdf->MultiCell(170,4, 'தமிழர் மரபு','R','L',0,0,$x+30,$y,true,0,false,false,0,'M',false);
```

Print as தமிழர் மர**பீ**  instead of தமிழர் மர**பு**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.